# Links between Functional Analysis and Graph Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, graph-theory

I am looking for a topic in Graph theory that uses Functional Analysis as an application. I don't know how to proceed in my search. All I want is to find somehow that would use Functional Analysis in Graph Theory. Any help/ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The theory of continuous graphs also known as [*graphons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphon) heavily relies on functional analysis of the Lebesgue space $L_1$ as one has to deal with certain limits of discrete objects with respect to the norm of $L_1$.
2. There is a characterisation of super-reflexive Banach space via impossibility of metric embedding of certain graphs (diamond graphs) into Banach spaces. See  papers by W.B. Johnson, A. Naor, M. Ostrovskii or G. Schechtman. For example:

> W. B. Johnson, G. Schechtman, [Diamond graphs and super-reflexivity](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bill.johnson/diamond09_06_08.pdf), *J. Topol. Anal.*, 1 (2009), **2**, 177–189.

3. There is a huge subfield of the theory operator algebras devoted to encoding graphs by certain C*-algebras (the so-called *graph algebras*). For example they generalise the Cuntz algebras which in a sense are building blocks of purely infinite algebras that are classifiable in certain sense. See these [introductory notes](http://www.math.ku.dk/english/research/conferences/2010_and_before/cuntzpimsner/files/tomforde_Talk1.pdf).

Comment: thank you so much , this was very helpful!!